# перевод из koi8-r c#

Tags: c#

Получаю ответ от сервера в кодировке koi8r, сразу пытаюсь преобразовать это в ASCII но на месте кириллицы появляются "?", тогда как с иностранным языком всё работает.

```
do
{
    numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(readingData, 0, readingData.Length);
    completeMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readingData, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
}
while (stream.DataAvailable);
```

Насколько я понял, кодировка Koi8r основана на ASCII и значения в диапазоне 0-127 у них вроде как совпадают, поэтому знаки(наверное) и иностранный язык отображаются корректно.

Как сделать, чтобы и русский язык тоже правильно работал? Из идей, было записать входной поток в список байт, а потом распечатывать его предварительно проверяя с совпадающим кодом из таблицы кодировки, но мне кажется, что должно быть более правильное решение.
С `GetEncoding("koi8r")` тоже не получилось.

Comment: Номер кодовой страницы 20866 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers, передайте номер кодовой страницы в эту функцию.

Comment: @ori попробовал и так тоже, не получается, всегда выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку? Покажите

Comment: @ori https://ibb.co/T0rsbPH и такое как не указывай, 20866 или koi8r

Comment: Ну тогда бери в руки [RFC 1489](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1489/) и вперед =) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET Core часть кодировок [была исключена](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider?view=net-6.0) из поддерживаемых по умолчанию и вынесена в отдельный [пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/7.0.0-preview.1.22076.8).

Установите его в проект и добавьте в Startup.cs строку:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```